# AngularJS minDate not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting the minDate for the datepicker to today, just as it is set on the angularJS bootstrap site, however it's not working properly.  I'm not getting any console errors, but it doesn't seem that minDat is really getting set or something. Thank you for your help!!

Here's the js

```
angular.module('SelfExam.Quiz', [])
    .controller('QuizCtrl',['$scope','MeetingsService', function($scope, MeetingsService) {

        // DATEPICKER
        //Sets the default date, making adjustments for meetings that would otherwise land on a weekend date.
        $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        if($scope.date.getDay() == 3 || $scope.date.getDay() == 4) {
            $scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() + 5);
        } else {
            $scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() + 3);
        }
        // Clears selection
        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.date = null;
        };

        // Disable weekend selection
        $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
            return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );

        };

        $scope.minDate = new Date();


        $scope.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.opened = true;
        };

        $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 0
        };

        $scope.initDate = new Date('2016-15-20');
        $scope.formats = ["shortDate"];
        $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
}]);
```

And the HTML

```
...
<div class="col-md-6">
           <p class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="shortDate" id="date-field" ng-model="date" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                           <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="cal-button"></i></button>
               </span>
          </p>

  </div>
...
```

Comment: So max-date is a string, and min-date is a Date object. Does the plugin accept both?

Comment: I would assume so. min and max date are as they were defined in the demo from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `min-date` and `max-date` in the html to `min` and `max`